# Converting HTML to odt, doc, docx

Tags: linux, document, docx, odt

Is there an easy way to convert HTML(with CSS styles and embedded images) to ODT, DOCX, DOC from the command line on linux server. I searched a lot but have not found a good option.
There was a problem the same way to convert to PDF, decided by wkhtmltopdf. Perhaps there are ways to convert the resulting PDF documents to other formats?

Comment: If someone wants the other way round, you can use [this great github tool named Docx2Html](https://github.com/Elagoht/Docx2Html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To convert to `odt` it's pretty easy after installing [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html).

After the relatively hard part: from `odt` (or even `html`) you can script (Open|Libre)Office via e.g. [`unoconv`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/maverick/unoconv)

Or you can like:

```
abiword --to=doc filename.odt
```

Also see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24096/handle-doc-docx-templates-on-a-headless-server-to-produce-pdfs-preferably-withou), and [this blog post](http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html).

HTH

Comment: Pandoc good thing - what i was looking for. But i have a problem with the tables - they are converted into regular sections - tables will be in each document and they are very important.

Comment: For pdf im using *wkhtmltopdf*, for server required to use xvfb - but result is perfect.

Comment: Just tried *pandoc*, it is bad. It does not work properly with image sizes, and from my searching it is a long standing problem.

Comment: Okay, just tried abiword. It have a minus — didn't worked either: being started like a converter in terminal it is just crashing with `Aborted(core dumped)`. But it have a plus — it is a graphical app, and it is possible to launch it, next open an html, next «save as» odt. But it have a minus: it moves an image for unknown reason to a second page *(and I didn't tried yet add more images to the html)*. Omg… Okay, screw it, I hope my university won't be against html instead of an office document…

Comment: As of September 2017, Pandoc still does not convert slightly more complex tables containing eg colspan https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1024

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert HTML into docx you may use a solution like [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com). You need to get the PRO version though because the free one does not include the conversion functionality.

Comment: Well, I am one of the developers of PHPDocX so I know the tool and I comment on it when I feel that it can be useful to anyone...I hope that there is nothing wrong with that :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong by itself, though one can question the sincerity of the answer if you post anonymously. What are you hiding? :) If you add "Disclosure: I am one of the developers of..." to such answers you make a much better impression.

Comment: @EduardoRamos how does phpdocx handle html > docx? Do I need to convert my html file with eternal resources to be entirely inline (including base64 encoded images) or can I send you a zip file?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on ruby [there is a gem based on libreoffice headless (with pyod/jod converter) and pdf tools](https://github.com/itkin/proselytism.git).

Comment: I've migrate on ruby now. Thanks a lot)

Answer (score 0):

I found soultion - is abiword in console variant.

Comment: How does this add to [this more elaborate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8384078/4575793)?